# Javascript split string by another string and include that another string that was used to split it into result

Tags: javascript, string, split

If I have this string: "MyStringToForSplitting" and I want to split it by this word "ring".
If I do this: `"MyStringToForSplitting".split('ring')`
I will get array that contains this elements:

1. MyS
2. ToForSplitting

I can't figure out best way to split it and include 'ring' in resulting array like this:

1.MyS

2.ring

3.ForSplitting

Comment: Sorry for duplication. Didn't find that one...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use *regex* and capture the split pattern:

```js
console.log("MyStringToForSplitting".split(/(ring)/));
```

```js
var s = "ring";
var p = new RegExp("(" + s + ")")
console.log("MyStringForSplitting".split(p))
```

Comment: What is ring is variable not hardcoded string?

Comment: You can construct the regular expression from the string variable and then use it for split. See the update.

Comment: And if you want to ignore casing then   new RegExp("(" + s + ")","i")    can be used